# What to do about declined flags I still believe are correct?

Tags: support, flags

Am I supposed to ask about each of them here? Is there another way to do it? Should I just not bother with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's a decline flag you disagree with or want clarification on you can [make](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/declined-flag-on-low-quality-question) a [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/why-was-this-flag-declined) about [it.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11711/why-was-this-offensive-flag-declined) If you have multiple flags you want to ask about at once, then you should just make one meta, though, to avoid clogging up the front page of meta. You can try [chat as well](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), since that's normally pretty active and filled with knowledgeable users, but meta would be the more appropriate place.